# Open bosonic string with boundary conditions representing D-branes

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions, branes

(This is the first part of Polchinski's problem 1.6, here it my attempt). I have the following boundary conditions on the $X^{25}$ component being $X^{25}(\tau,0) = 0$ and $X^{25}(\tau,l) = y$ for some constant $y$. I am trying to modify the general solution for the open bosonic string given in Polchinski's equation (1.3.22) repeated here for clarity
\begin{equation}
X^i(\tau,\sigma) = x^i + \frac{p^i}{p^+}\tau + i\sqrt{2\alpha'}\sum\frac{1}{n}\alpha_n^i\exp(-\frac{\pi inc\tau}{l})\cos(\frac{\pi n\sigma}{l}).
\end{equation}
Now, my initial attempt has that from the first condition,
\begin{equation}
X^{25}(\tau,\sigma = 0) = x^{25} + \frac{p^{25}\tau}{p^+}+i\sqrt{2\alpha'}\sum\frac{1}{n}\alpha_n^{25}\exp(-\frac{\pi inc\tau}{l})(1) = 0
\end{equation}
while from the second condition I have
\begin{equation}
X^{25}(\tau,\sigma = l) = x^{25} + \frac{p^{25}\tau}{p^+}+i\sqrt{2\alpha'}\sum\frac{1}{n}\alpha_n^{25}\exp(-\frac{\pi inc\tau}{l})\cos(\pi n) = y.
\end{equation}
If I let $p^{25} = 0$, $x^{25} = y$, and restrict $n = \pm \frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{3}{2},\cdots$ then the second condition is satisfied but the first won't be since the cosine term is already at $1$ and I have left over terms. So my question is then what am I missing from the solution if I let
\begin{equation}
X^{25} = y + i\sqrt{2\alpha'}\sum\frac{1}{n}\alpha_n^{25}\exp(-\frac{\pi inc\tau}{l})\cos(\frac{\pi n\sigma}{l})
\end{equation}
since this won't satisfy the first condition when $\sigma = 0\implies X^{25} =0$. I could multiply by a $\sigma$ dependence on the oscillator term and divide by a factor of $l$ to keep units dimensionless but this wouldn't make sense to me. Unless this is correct and I am just glossing over a very simple detail (which is of course possible). Any help or suggestions is useful, thanks.

(This is a problem from the textbook but I am just doing the ones over winter break that I didn't do during class).